# TortoiseSVN - get a list of all revisions for a specific tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, release, tagging, revision

In the SVN repository I'm working with there are several subfolders - **branch**, **trunk** and **tags**.

The **tags** directory is what I'm interested in. It contains tags for the releases (we follow the scheme **major.minor.maintenance** for example **01.00.07**).

I would like to know if there is some sort of a feature in TortoiseSVN to obtain **all** the revisions that "belong" to the given release or even better - simply see which version your current revision is for. Obviously revisions that go ahead of the last release (since they belong to a release that has yet to happen) don't fall in this category.

**EDIT:** Comment by @royalTS helps a little bit but what I'm looking for is something like a column (similar to the already present *Date*, *Author*, *Revision* etc.) with the release tag next to each revision.

Comment: Are the information from the log (Show Log) not enough?

Comment: I don't see any version tag in the show log. I also checked in the repo-browser but still nothing. That is why I posted this question. ;) "Show all -> Show range..." also doesn't give me the option to filter based on version tags.

Comment: @royalTS Aaaah, I know what you mean. When I right click on the specific version tag and "show log" it gives me all the revisions for that tag. I was however wondering if I can see the version tag when I simply open "show log" (right click in the SVN folder in Explorer) right next to the revision.

Comment: so then this fine enough?

Comment: Nope, I'd like to see the tag next to the revision in show log. If it's possible...When you open logging window you have several columns (Revision, Author, Actions, Date etc.). I'd like to see a column with the release tag.

Comment: I think this is not possible without creating some script by yourself, since the tag is just a new revision

Comment: I have never created such a script. Is it even possible to use something like that when you are not administering the repository (it's a remote one)?